# Delta Epsilon help and IFF statement order

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L \mbox{ iff} \lim_{x\to a}f(x)-L =0 $$ 
Hints please

I'm new to delta epsilons

First how do I prove a iff statement in which order

Comment: do I assume the left side holds only if the right side holds

Comment: "$A$ iff $B$" (short for "$A$ if and only if $B$") means that if $B$ is true then $A$ is true, and if $B$ is false then $A$ is false. Another way of saying the same thing (and the way that you usually prove an iff statement) is that if $B$ is true then $A$ is true, and if $A$ is true then $B$ is true.

Comment: O I have to prove the righthand side

Comment: If it is an iff statement, then you have to both prove the right hand side (given the left hand side) and the left hand side (given the right hand side).

Comment: Oh so both ways

Comment: So then is it safe to assume Case1: LHS is by defn then I try to get the RHS into the same delta epsilon proof format

Comment: Case 2: given RHS I Have to show LHS is equivlant

Comment: Then I also have to show If not RHS then Not LHS and Im done

Comment: You have to 1) assume LHS and prove RHS, then 2) assume RHS and prove LHS. ("If not RHS then not LHS" is the same thing as "If LHS then RHS"; try listing out the cases if you're not convinced.)

Comment: OHHHH OK THANKS SOOO MUCHHH

Answer (score 0):

This is the general approach to proving if and only if statements:

Step 1) "Left to Right": Assume the left hand side holds true.  Show that the right hand side follows.

Step 2) "Right to Left": Assume the right hand side holds true.  Show that the left hand side follows.

You can vary either step as necessary to make either step easier, e.g., for step 2: Assume the left hand side is false.  Show that the right hand side must be false.

Here is your particular definition: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\vert x-a\vert<\delta$ implies $\vert f(x)-L\vert < \epsilon$.  Do you see how to make one side follow from the other?